# scipy.ndimage.correlate but updating of values while computing

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, scipy

I need an array of the sums of 3x3 neighboring cells with products based on a kernel of a different array with the same size (this is exactly [scipy.ndimage.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.correlate.html#scipy.ndimage.correlate) up to this point). But when a value for the new array is calculated it has to be updated immediately instead of using the value from the original array for the next computation involving that value. I have written this slow code to implement it myself, which is working perfectly fine (although too slow for me) and delivering the expected result:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        AArr[y,x] += laplaceNeighborDifference(x,y)

def laplaceNeighborDifference(x,y,z):
    global w, h, AArr
    return -AArr[y,x]+AArr[(y+1)%h,x]*.2+AArr[(y-1)%h,x]*.2+AArr[y,(x+1)%w]*.2+AArr[y,(x-1)%w]*.2+AArr[(y+1)%h,(x+1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y-1)%h,(x+1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y+1)%h,(x-1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y-1)%h,(x-1)%w]*.05
```

In my approach the kernel is coded directly. Although as an array (to be used as a kernel) it would be written like this:

```
[[.05,.2,.05],
 [.2 ,-1,.2 ],
 [.05,.2,.05]]
```

The SciPy implementation would work like this:

```
AArr += correlate(AArr, kernel, mode='wrap')
```

But obviously when I use [scipy.ndimage.correlate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.correlate.html#scipy.ndimage.correlate) it calculates the values entirely based on the original array and doesn't update them as it computes them. At least I think that is the difference between my implementation and the SciPy implementation, feel free to point out other differences if I've missed one. My question is if there is a similar function to the aforementioned with desired results or if there is an approach to code it which is faster than mine?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Numba** to do that efficiently:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def laplaceNeighborDifference(AArr,w,h,x,y):
    return -AArr[y,x]+AArr[(y+1)%h,x]*.2+AArr[(y-1)%h,x]*.2+AArr[y,(x+1)%w]*.2+AArr[y,(x-1)%w]*.2+AArr[(y+1)%h,(x+1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y-1)%h,(x+1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y+1)%h,(x-1)%w]*.05+AArr[(y-1)%h,(x-1)%w]*.05

@nb.njit('void(float64[:,::1],int64,int64)')
def compute(AArr,width,height):
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            AArr[y,x] += laplaceNeighborDifference(AArr,width,height,x,y)
```

Note that **modulus are generally very slow**. This is better to remove them by computing the border separately of the main loop. The resulting code should be much faster without any modulus.

Comment: If I use numba my code actually stops working. I'm not really that familiar with numba, but errors I get (Overflow and different image output altogether) seem to hint at the possibility that numba rounds the values in the background or something. I'm sorry that I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working" exactly? A segmentation fault or python errors? If you want to debug the problem, you can just remove the `@nb.njit` decorators. If the problem appear only with the Numba decorators, you can try to replace the `@nb.njit('void(float64[:,::1],int64,int64)')` with just `@nb.njit`. If the problem is still there and is not just a typing issue, it could be a bug of Numba or an unsupported feature but it would be surprising on this simple code.

Comment: Regarding the rounding issue you are talking about, it might be related to part of your code requiring value to be in a given range. In this case you can just call a min/max function on each value to be sure it is in a correct range.

Comment: If I just write `nb.njit` I get overflow warnings and the array has different values than if I just remove those two lines.